# Why the plots are not using full width of the page?

Tags: svg

I want to have a 2 x 2 grid to present four plots. The width of the plots should be automatically adjusted to utilize the full width of the page (keeping decent margins on the sides).

The maximum width of the page must be 1000 pixels.

**My code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[papersize={1000px,1000px}]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty} % Remove page numbers

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[Noisy Plot]{\includesvg[width=0.5\textwidth]{test.svg}\label{fig:noisy}}\hfill
  \subfloat[Good Plot]{\includesvg[width=0.5\textwidth]{test.svg}\label{fig:good}}\\
  \subfloat[Nice Plot]{\includesvg[width=0.5\textwidth]{test.svg}\label{fig:nice}}\hfill
  \subfloat[Signal Plot]{\includesvg[width=0.5\textwidth]{test.svg}\label{fig:signal}}
  \caption{My test plots}
  \label{fig:four-plots}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Problem:** As shown in the figure above, the plots are not utilizing the whole available width on the page. The plots are quite small. How can I increase the width of the plots while maintaining aspect ratio?

Comment: well textwidth and paperwidth are two different things. Set the margins to zero, see the geometry documentation.

Comment: Check margin and also check the whitespace around svg plots.